# How to count number of leading spaces in a string in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, count, whitespace

I want to know how to count the number of leading spaces in a string in Swift.

Say, if the string is `"  Hello world "`, the result should be `2`

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to use `prefix(while:)`, and count how many characters you got:

```
yourString.prefix(while: { $0 == " " }).count
```